# Is there a limit to how big an Azure role package can be?

Tags: windows, deployment, azure, cloud

I'm tempted to [include a ton of binary files right into an Azure role package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6152466/57428) so that it can become several hundred megabytes in size. Before I do that I have to ask - is there a limit to how big an Azure role package can be?

Answer (score 5):

The limit I believe is 600 MB (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/windowsazuremanagement/thread/65620bdb-3439-4ce0-8f17-561914d325ac). However as suggested by Travis, you should look into storing items like images, videos etc. in blob storage because even if you change a single image, you will need to redeploy your application.

Another thing you would need to consider with large packages is timeout errors when deploying your code through Windows Azure portal when you are specifying the package file source as a file on your computer. An alternative to that would be to upload this package file in blob storage before hand and specify the blob URL when creating a deployment through Windows Azure portal.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Gaurav

Comment: +1.  You can also use something like http://boostrap.codeplex.com to download additional resources you need from your storage account and install it (rather than package it).

Answer (score 0):

A few hundred megabytes is not an issue on a role package for Azure. There are limitations for storage account sizes, which your packages needs to get dumped into if it is large enough of about 100gigs. Outside of the huge amount of time it would take to upload the package and spin up a new instance, it should be acceptable.

For large binary files, I would consider using a storage account instead of inside your deployment package. The larger the deployment package, the longer it takes to spin up a new instance - which already takes like 20 minutes now. Since the link indicates most of this storage need is for related COM data it might not be an easy option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related size issue: if all these files you are putting into your upload payload appear within an IIS site, they will need to be processed by the IISConfigurator. If you have "too many of these" (not a hard and fast number, sorry, but more than 10,000), you may get timeout errors. The issue is discussed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/09/handing-web-role-exception-this-request-operation-sent-to-net-pipe-localhost-iisconfigurator-did-not-receive-a-reply-within-the-configured-timeout-00-01-00.aspx).